# Is it possible to load & export to BQ from google compute disk?

Tags: google-bigquery

How do I load to bigquery from compute disk? and should this be faster then loading from Google CLoud storage?
And the same for export. thanks a alot

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like an interesting idea, but there are only 2 ways to load data into BigQuery:

- A .csv or .json file in GCS (as you mention). Note that they can be gzip compressed, for faster transfer times, while uncompressed files will get faster processing times.
- Or send data to the API via a POST request.

As you mention, leaving file in GCS is the faster and recommended way for large data imports and exports.